# secure client side sql querys?

Tags: android, sql, cordova, client, phonegap

I am currently building a cordova App for Android. Now I want to run a simple sql query to increase a Number on a database every time a button in the app is clicked.
How can i realize this? I mean if I run a Query client side, then someone could just run the Query million times and break the server.. I don't know how to make sure everyone can just run the query once. Has someone an idea?

thanks!

Comment: Expand your approach.  You will have to keep track of user activity in order to restrict a person to once a day.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your approach using a table that tracks users who run the query and apply an unique key. You should identify the user with an unique identifier. Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html)

In this way you don't need to increase an integer column. Just do a count(*) on the table and the result will be the number of clicks